# Web service with NFC

Tags: android, web-services, nfc

I have a problem when I want to make a webservice stops the app is not that any ideas?

```
private String dumpTagData(Parcelable p) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Tag tag = (Tag) p;
    byte[] id = tag.getId();
    sb.append("ID Producto:").append(getDec(id)).append("\n");
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>

    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(0);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

    sb.append("Nombre:").append(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME)).append("\n");
    sb.append("Costo:").append(parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST)).append("\n");
    sb.append("Descripción:").append(parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)).append("\n");

    sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually you don't want to let a server stop a client app, when it comes to webservices. It is much like a TV-station shutting down your television.